# Variable defined and used as a method parameter but value never used so getting ESLint Unused Variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jestjs, eslint

I defined an object like below :

```
const myObject = {
    id:"32443",
    data : { myData : "Some DATA" }
}
```

I only need this object to pass to my jest mockImplementation method to muck mongodb update :

```
jest
      .spyOn(myRepo, 'update')
      .mockImplementation((myObject) => myMockData);
```

test works fine, but I getting **ESLint Unused Variables**  error. I need the eslint to be active, any way that I can get raid of this without disabling it?

Comment: I could see myObject is not used in the test( ESLint Unused Variables, yes it is true), it is curious for now how the test is ok ? could you please share your test case?

Comment: @ArulmozhiManikandan I passed it to .mockImplementation((myObject) => myMockData);

Comment: You're not using `myObject`. The `myObject` on `mockImplementation` is just a parameter of the arrow function you're passing to it, not the object defined object above.

Comment: Could you please test is `myMockData to be myObject` i think it will fail.

Comment: I can confirm that test works fine, and yes, I aware that I'm not using this object and only pass it as parameter, so I want a way to get raid of ESLint error regarding this object

Comment: you cannot pass a variable as a parameter while defining the function, it can be passed only on the function

Comment: `(myObject)` is not using the defined object.... So lint is correct in saying you are not using it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off linting just for this variable.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const myObject = {
  id:"32443",
  data : { myData : "Some DATA" }
}
```

Pl refer this doc for more info - [disabling-rules-with-inline-comments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments)

Answer (score 0):

you are not pasing my object as a parameter. You are stating that the anonimous function has a parameter myobject, but this has nothing to do with `const myObject`

```
my_Object= {candi: true};    
(my_Object) => my_Object=undefined;
alert(my_Object.candi)
```

this prints true.